# Is this part of a sentence grammatically correct? "I ride a bicycle 'to or not to' go to the school"

Tags: sentence-construction

> *I ride a bicycle to or not to go to the school.*

Is ***to or not to*** correct expression? I doubt joining two words which have not a lexical meaning but a grammatical meaning with a conjunction is possible as 'or' in 'I may or will play soccer' or in 'I am or was happy'.

Comment: "to or not to" doesn't make sense. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty I'm trying to join two words which have not a lexical meaning but a grammatical meaning with a conjunction as 'or' in 'I jump and or or play.'

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty Or as in 'I may or shall come'

Comment: but the preposition "to" has a lexical meaning.

Comment: @James K It is a infinitive mark.

Comment: While "may or will" and "am or was" don't make sense to me, there are many similar examples with auxiliaries that do make sense and are valid (in appropriate contexts): "can and will", "couldn't—or wouldn't—", "was, is, and will be", "did or didn't", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't say those things. You would have to say "I ride a bicycle, whether or not I am going to school", or simply "I ride my bicycle everywhere". Why bring school into it at all?

*May or will* and *may or shall* don't make sense. How can you be both uncertain and certain that you will do something?

It would be possible to say "I am - or I *was* - happy", implying that something has just happened to make you unhappy.

Comment: Thank you, then, 'not' can't modify 'not' as in 'not not happy' regardless of a double negative?

Comment: What's wrong with 'not unhappy'?

Comment: No, not 'not unhappy', 'not not happy.' The first 'not' modifies the second 'not,' not 'happy.'

Comment: So what else do you think 'not not happy' means? It makes no sense whatever to  me.